# Escaping name of JavaScript object in node console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I am simply trying to access an object which name starts with ':' from the Javascript console.

Here is how the object looks like and I want to access escrow:

```
{
   'compiled': 
   {
      'contracts':
       { 
          ':escrow':   
           { assembly: { 
              '.code': [Array], 
              '.data': [Object] 
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am trying, but always get a undefined error message:

```
compiled.contracts.escrow
```

Comment: You're getting `undefined` because `"escrow"` is clearly not the same as `":escrow"`.  Use `[ ]`: `compiled.contracts[":escrow"]`

Comment: @Pointy please add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: did not even know that this was allowed

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate question out there, if not dozens of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property name is not a valid *identifier* (something that would work as a variable name), the property must be accessed with the `[ ]` operator:

```
compiled.contracts[":escrow"]
```

The `[ ]` operator otherwise does exactly the same thing as `.` in chain of object property references.